# where is Zimbra accounts information location?

Tags: centos, zimbra

Where does Zimbra 8 (installed in Centos 6.4) stores accounts information e.g. email address, password, name ... I want to find its physical address. I couldn't find these information in the database created by Zimbra!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of informations are stored in the `OpenLDAP`, by default, the `Zimbra` OpenLdap directory is `/opt/zimbra/data/ldap`